# Can't access methods on object's prototype

Tags: javascript

I can create a `Cat` object and set a method on it's prototype to print out the cat's name.

```js
var log = function(message) {
  var results = $('#result');
  results.append('<p>' + message + '</p>');
};

function Cat(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Cat.prototype.speak = function() {
  log('My name is ' + this.name);
};

var fluffy = new Cat('Fluffy');
var tiddles = new Cat('Tiddles');

log(fluffy.name);
fluffy.speak();
log(tiddles.name);
tiddles.speak();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

However, when I try to set the cat's prototype to an animal, I can't access the `speak` method:

```
function Animal(name, sound) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sound = sound;

    this.speak = function() {
        log(sound + '! My name is ' + name);
    };
}

function Cat(name) {
    this.prototype = new Animal(name, 'Meow');
}

var fluffy = new Cat('Fluffy');

fluffy.speak();  // TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Why does `fluffy` not get the `speak()` method of its prototype?

Comment: If you want to learn how to do inheritance in JS, [please read this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance) . `prototype` is a property of the **constructor function**, not the *instance*. *"Why does `fluffy` not get the `speak()` method of its prototype?"* Because it's not on its prototype. You are never mutating `Cat.prototype`.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling, it was the scoping of the `this` that was missing.  Quick read, problem solved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to learn how to do inheritance in JS, [please read this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance) . `prototype` is a property of the **constructor function**, not the *instance*.

> Why does `fluffy` not get the `speak()` method of its prototype?

Because it's not on its prototype. You are never mutating `Cat.prototype`. The way you set up `Animal`, you would have to call `Animal` inside `Cat` instead:

```
function Cat(name) {
    Animal.call(this, name, 'Meow');
}
```

But if you want proper prototype inheritance, define `speak` on `Animal.prototype` and set up inheritance via `Object.create`:

```
function Animal(name, sound) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sound = sound;
}

Animal.prototype.speak = function() {
    log(this.sound + '! My name is ' + this.name);
};

function Cat(name) {
    Animal.call(this, name, 'Meow');
}
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
```

Comment: Good info, I just want to add that JavaScript is NOT an object oriented programming language. It can definitely be set up to act like one; but, it is not one.

Comment: souldn't you also set the Cat.prototype.constructor to Cat ?

Comment: @Toby: JS just doesn't use class-based inheritance, that's all. It's still all about objects.

Comment: @DRC: if it is anticipated that `constructor` is going to be used or if you are building a library then yes. It has no internal use though.

Comment: Whyy does `Cat.prototype` need to be set outside the constructor?

Comment: @FelixKling "It's still all about objects.", all but primitives though! :)

Comment: @BanksySan: because you want to set it once, not every time the constructor is called.

Comment: @FelixKling Makes sense.  Is it even possible?

Comment: @BanksySan: sure, but depending on what exactly you are doing, you could end up with a prototype for each instance in which case you gained nothing at all.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you set `speak` as a privileged method inside `Animal` constructor.

However, that constructor is never called for `Cat` instances.

Moreover, you can't use `prototype` property to modify internal `[[prototipe]]` and change the object from which properties should be inherited. You can use non standard `__proto__` or ECMAScript6 `Object.setProtetipeOf`, but better don't do that.

Instead, better use this approach:

```
function SuperClass(args) {
    // Here add SuperClass privileged properties
}

// Here add public properties to SuperClass.prototype

function SubClass(otherArgs) {
    // Add SuperClass privileged properties to SubClass instances:
    SuperClass.call(this, args);

    // Here add SubClass privileged properties
}

// Make SubClass instances inherit from SuperClass.prototype:
SubClass.prototype = Object.create(SuperClass.prototype);

// Fix constructor property, overriden in the line above
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;

// Here add public properties to SubClass.prototype
```

```js
function log(message) {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<p>' + message + '</p>';
}

function Animal(name, sound) {
  this.name = name;
  this.sound = sound;
}

Animal.prototype.speak = function() {
  log(this.sound + '! My name is ' + this.name);
};

function Cat(name) {
  Animal.call(this, name, 'Meow');
}

Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;

var fluffy = new Cat('Fluffy');

fluffy.speak();
```