# What harm can omitting prototype.constructor cause when inheriting?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27208370/442351) on a question about inheritance in JavaScript, [Oriol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529630/oriol) adds the line

```
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;
```

What is this for?

Could you give me an example of one (or some) *bad things* that could happen if this were omitted and the inheritance was simply:

```
function Animal(name, sound) {
  this.name = name;
  this.sound = sound;
}

function Cat(name) {
  Animal.call(this, name, 'Meow');
}

Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
```

Comment: [**Object.prototype.constructor**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)

Comment: @adeneo, Thanks, but that tells me what it is, but not why it is or why it's important.

Comment: The `constructor` property is mostly just FYI and by default holds a reference to the `function` it was defined for. The property isn't used by JavaScript itself, though it could be used by some libraries or tools. The assignment of `Cat` as the `constructor` just restores the value it held before the whole `prototype` was replaced -- http://jsfiddle.net/u3p9gghv/.